# How to do this in Hive?

Tags: hive

I have 2 questions in hive.
1. I have data like 234336899. if the last 3 digits are i.e 899 >500 it will print 999 otherwise if 899 <500 it should print 000.
Can you please tell me how to do it in hive?

2. I have another scenario like input as follows.

0 1 2
3 1 2
0 1 4
3 1 4

i want to print output as follows.

0 1
3 1
1 2
1 4

How to do it in Hive?

Thanks in adv,

Comment: what have you tried before asking SO?

Answer (score 0):

Your first question can be solved as below:

```
create table sample (col1 bigint);

insert into table sample values(234336899),(234336399);

select 
col1,
case when substr(col1,-3) > 500 then '999'
     when substr(col1,-3) < 500 then '000'
end as case_col1
from sample;
```

Here the **substr** hive function has been used to take the last 3 digits from col1.